# NetworkX: how to select subgraph based on a set of edge indexes?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

For:

```
G = nx.petersen_graph()   # Example only, it could be any graph
E = G.edges()

while many_many_loops:
    edge_set = my_function(...)  # Returns a set, say { 3, 9, 4 }
    T = G.edge_subgraph( ... )   # Contains only edges 3, 4, and 9.
```

How should I efficiently produce the appropriate arguments to `edge_subgraph()` given that `E` is not indexable?

(I can think of many awkward ways, but my knowledge of python and NetworkX is only enough to make me think that there *must* be an easy and elegant way, but not enough to know what it *is*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is easy (and of course in hind-sight obvious):

```
E = list(G.edges())

T = G.edge_subgraph(E[e] for e in edge_set)
```

The `list()` function converts E into a list, which can be indexed.